# FlatBuffers with Autotools

Tags: flatbuffers

FlatBuffers build is based on cmake, I don't have(and cant install) cmake on target system where I want to build it
FlatBuffers don't seem have support for autotools, have anyone tried to use autotools(./configure, make, make install) to build FlatBuffers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can build `flatc` on your development system (or you can generate code somewhere that is not your target system), actually building on the target system involves the generated header, and the headers in `include/flatbuffers`, i.e. it is header-only and as such doesn't need any build system to build it. Just point the build of your actual project to where these headers are (`-I`).

Comment: Actually I want to use it on hp nonstop which does not have cmake as of now, would there be any kind of workaround for this. I am trying to use flatcc, the one with no c++